# How to set specific style for layout in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need specific style sheet for specific layout.

for example have `index.html.erb` need specific style sheet.

why need this because any layout have style of body different for this layout.

when load `index.html.erb` load by `custom.css.scss`

Comment: do you want this `custom.css.scss` file to load only in `index` of every controller or specific controller?

Comment: in specific controller for example `index` in `PostController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout file, let's say `application.html.erb` file:

Use conditional stylesheet: 
If it's `PostController` and 'index, then load **custom.css.scss** else **custom2.css.scss**

**Edit:** Load all styles except `custom.css.scss`. Then use a conditional statement to load `custom.css` only in `PostController`'s `index` method

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style1' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style2' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style3' %>
<% if params[:controller] == 'post' && params[:action] == 'index' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `content_for`/`yield` is probably better here.

Comment: but i have many of style sheet file in this code choose between two style sheet only . i need read all style sheet normal but in `index` load `custom.css.scss`

Comment: @Emu Thanks you but some `custom.css.scss. affect in another `layout`